# LinearLayout with two Recyclerviews not sharing the space according to row data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create the 2 recycler views in LinearLayout.
The RecyclerView 1 should be fixed and it should not push the RecyclerView 2 so to achieve that I have added parameter `android:layout_weight="1"` to both RecyclerView 1 and 2. But I found the issue when there is less items in RecyclerView 2 it shows whitespace at bottom. Is there anyway to resize the RecyclerView 1 and 2 based on the content/row with both RecyclerView 1 and 2 visible in the screen.

[image]

**EDIT**

My existing layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_16sdp" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv2"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_16sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Row layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/rowtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set the width of the recyclerview to wrapContent . Also share the xml for better understading .

Comment: Try changing the height to wrarpContent for rv2 for it to collapse .

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar I tried providing rv2 height as wrap_content and removed layout_weight it works partially, if there are more data in rv2 it is expanding and rv1 isn't visible?

Comment: Can you share visuals of the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:weightSum="2"` In your Linear Layout containing RecyclerViews.